# PHP: \Exception or Exception inside a namespace

Tags: php, exception

I am trying to handle some errors in my api. However I tried some so many ways to execute what it's needed to it done?

In the code i used Exception, \Exception, another class extending to Exception, "use \Exception".
None of these options works.
What i need to do execute the block catch?

```
  //Piece of source in the begin of file
    namespace Business\Notifiers\Webhook;
    use \Exception;
    class MyException extends \Exception {}

    //Piece of source from my class
    try{

        $products = $payment->getProducts();
        if(count($products) == 0)
            return;
        $flight_id = $products[0]->flight_id;
        $this->message = 'Sir, we have a new request: ';
        $products = null; //Chagind it to null to force an error..
        foreach($products as $product){

            $this->appendAttachment(array(
                'color' => '#432789',
                'text' => 
                    "*Name:* $product->name $product->last_name \n" . 
                    "*Total Paid:*  R\$$product->price\n",
                'mrkdwn_in' => ['text', 'pretext']
            ));
        }
    } catch(Exception $e){
        $this->message = "A exception occurred ";
    } catch(\Exception $e){
        $this->message = "A exception occurred e";
    } catch(MyException $e){
        $this->message = "A exception occurred";
    }
```

Comment: You need to actually throw an exception...

Comment: `throw new Exception('throwing an exception...');` https://secure.php.net/Exceptions

Comment: I'm forcing the exception. I changed the $products to null, after this line im using foreach.

Comment: This does not throw an exception (or fatal error), it's a warning. `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you need to understand the difference between an exception and an error:

1. http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php
2. http://php.net/manual/en/ref.errorfunc.php

Trying to foreach over a null value will not yield an exception, but trigger an error. You can use an error handler to wrap an error in an exception, as such:

```
<?php

function handle ($code, $message)
{
    throw new \Exception($message, $code);
}

set_error_handler('handle');

// now this will fail
try {
    $foo = null;
    foreach ($foo as $bar) {
    }
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

However in your code, you can simply check if $products is null and if so, throw an exception:

```
if (!$products) {
    throw new \Exception('Could not find any products')
}
foreach($products as $product) { ...
```

Comment: Foreaching over a NULL value will not trigger an error. PHP throws a warning.

Comment: Deep down, a warning is just an error with E_WARNING level. The code will work either way. You can monitor for only certain types of errors by specifying the second parameter of the set_error_handler() function - http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Answer (score 22):

The accepted answer above give the real cause of the issue, but did not answer the topic

If in case someone is interested and is looking for

**what is the difference between Exception and \Exception inside a namespace?**

Still valid against PHP 7.3.5:

1. \Exception: Refer to Exception in **root** namespace
2. Exception: Refer to Exception in **current** namespace
3. PHP does not fall back to root namespace, if the class cannot be found in current name space, it emits an error.

---

```
<?php
namespace Business;
try {
    throw new Exception("X"); //  Uncaught Error: Class 'Business\Exception' not found
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Exception: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

---

```
<?php
namespace Business;
class Exception extends \Exception {} // means \Business\Exception extends \Exception

$a = new Exception('hi'); // $a is an object of class \Business\Exception
$b = new \Exception('hi'); // $b is an object of class \Exception
```

Comment: Further clarification can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44867502/2511355. If you haven't extended the global Exception class, you should choose `use \Exception`

Comment: The only thing to add: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php