# Difference between (Exception $e) and (\Exception $e) in try{}catch(){}

Tags: php, laravel

What is the difference between `(Exception $e)` and `(\Exception $e)` in `try{}catch(){}` 
What is the impact of 'back-slash \' before `Exception`?

Comment: yea same answer.

Comment: Same question same answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `\` in front of class name, it mean you call the `class` from global space. If you don't use `\`, it will call the class in same namespace with your code. But if you don't use `namespace` in your code, it will call class from global space.

Example:

```
<?php
namespace Module\Example;

class Test
{
    try{

    } catch(Exception $e) { // will look up Module\Example\Exception

    }

    try{

    } catch(\Exception $e) { // will look up Exception from global space

    }
}
```

You can check this documentation for more detail.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php

Answer (score 1):

Back slash like this `\Exception` represents Global namespace. It specifies that the functions in the class are called from global namespace and it will not overwrite the function with same name within the same namespace.

#### According to `php.net` -

> Without any namespace definition, all class and function definitions are placed into the global space - as it was in PHP before namespaces were supported. Prefixing a name with \ will specify that the name is required from the global space even in the context of the namespace.